# Why is my AppBar MUI styled component not changing style on state change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, navbar, styled-components

I'm trying to change the app bar color upon scrolling. I used a MaterialUI styled feature to create my app bar. I checked the value of the state in the console and it is changing correctly. Unfortunately, the app bar does not react to the state change of my passed prop on the styled component which is supposed to be the trigger for the component background color.

Here is the styled component code:

```
 const AppBar = styled(MUIAppBar)(({ theme, scrollNav }) => ({
      backgroundColor: !scrollNav ? '#E6EEF4 !important' : 'red !important',
      position: 'fixed',
      color: '#232F3D',
      paddingTop: theme.spacing(2),
      paddingBottom: theme.spacing(2),
    }))
```

Here is the trigger for the state change:

```
 const [scrollNav, setScrollNav] = useState(false)
  const changeNav = () => {
    setScrollNav(window.scrollY >= 96 ? true : false)
  }
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', changeNav)
  }, [])
```

Here is how I pass the state to the styled component:

```
<AppBar position="fixed" scrollNav={scrollNav}></AppBar>
```

Comment: Please check this
https://mui.com/styles/basics/#adapting-based-on-props

Comment: Hi, I tried to use that approach but I can't access the `theme` of material UI

Answer (score 0):

This example may helpful

> Spread the props

[Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-cdn-f160l?file=/src/App.js:0-781)

```
import { styled } from "@mui/styles";
import { Button, createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material";
import { useState } from "react";
const appTheme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#e56339"
    }
  }
});
const StyledDiv = styled("div")(({ theme, ...props }) => ({
  // background: theme.palette.primary?.main, //theme usage
  background: props?.toggled ? "red" : "blue"
}));

export default function App() {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div>
      <ThemeProvider theme={appTheme}>
        <StyledDiv toggled={toggle}>Styled div</StyledDiv>
      </ThemeProvider>
      <div style={{margin:10}}>
      <Button variant="contained"  onClick={() => setToggle((pre) => !pre)}>toggle</Button>
    </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```